# eMail with Conflicting Headers not blocked in MS365

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

On occasion, a company receives eMail with two header fields (“Received” and “From”) containing data that contradict each other drastically.  Should they not expect their anti-spam system to flag or block items with contradictions in these fields?

For example, they received an eMail which contained [almost exactly] these two headers:

**Received**: from [107.52.51.26] by web315204.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon,28 Oct 2013 04:28:04 PDT

**From**: Barry Smith smithbsure@att.net>

Obviously, eMail from an @att.net address isn’t coming from a server on the domain yahoo.com, and Yahoo isn’t forwarding AT&T’s eMail.  There were no other headers indicating that the item was sent “OnBehalfOf”, or “Forwarded-by”, or “By_Proxy” or any other such.

Should I write a utility to scan incoming eMail for such conflicts, or look more closely at their spam filtering to block this kind of eMail?  Their eMail system is Hosted Exchange on MS-365.  *My central question is*, where specifically do I look in MS-365 to get this type of conflicted eMail blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, eMail from an @att.net address isn’t coming from a server
>   on the domain yahoo.com

While that MIGHT be true in this instance, it isn't true for a lot of email.

For instance, you might have a `RECEIVED` header that says something like:

Received: from [107.52.51.26] by exchange01.domain.local via HTTP; Mon,28 Oct 2013 04:28:04 PDT

and a `FROM` header like:

From: Barry Smith smith@domain.com>

The actual server sending (in the Received header) may not be representative of the sender's domain.  It might be a mail server that hosts MANY domains or it could be the last leg of an email's path (for instance being routed through a SaaS antivirus/antispam service before delivery).

**What you are really after is SPF records for the domain.**  That is how to look for spam in this instance.  They will correspond and tell you whether an email that is coming from bob@domain.com should have come from webmailserver004.sillygoose.net or not.

Comment: Specifically, where I am finding in MS-365 a way to get this type of conflicted eMail blocked is in "Exchange admin center", "protection", "content filter", "Advanced spam filtering options", "Conditional Sender ID filtering".

Comment: 'Turns out Yahoo does now provide eMail server service for AT&T.